# document.getElementById('rowtxtConsidAmt') null only in mozilla

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I am gettig the above error in mozila , but its works well in IE

Javascript:

```
function ValidateForm() { 

    var objtxtStampDutyAmt= document.getElementById(contentPlaceholderId + 'txtStampDutyAmt');
     if( objtxtStampDutyAmt != null && document.getElementById('rowtxtStampDutyAmt').style.display != 'none' )
     {
        if(trim(objtxtStampDutyAmt.value) == '')
        { 
            alert("Please enter Stamp Duty Amount");
            objtxtStampDutyAmt.focus(); 
            return false;
        }
     }
}
```

ASPX:

```
  <tr id="rowTxtConsidAmt">
        <td class="formlabel">
            <asp:Label ID="lblConsidAmt" runat="server" Text="Consideration Amount" />
            &nbsp; (Rs.)&nbsp;<font class="textMandatory">*</font>
        </td>
   </tr>
```

Call is here:

```
<td colspan="6" class="formgrouptitle">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnPayment" runat="server" Text="Click here to make payment" CssClass="Button"
                                OnClick="btnPayment_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm()" />
                        </td>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you add the code for the element `rowtxtConsidAmt`?

Comment: How are you running this function? Is it delayed until the DOM is ready?

Comment: can you show us the markup which is using that id?

Comment: Why are you testing in Mozilla? It was discontinued half a decade ago. Does it work in Firefox? Does it work in Chrome? Safari? Opera? What versions of IE have you tested it in? Does the document include an element with that id (since you are using .NET I wouldn't be surprised if you were getting browser sniffing delivering different markup to different browsers).

Comment: @Quentin the OP probably means Firefox.

Comment: Also, what is the value of "contentPlaceholderId"?

Comment: @Matt — probably, it is still an inadequate range of cross-browser testing though.

Comment: Please show the HTML markup as it's sent to the browser (use 'View Source'), I don't know how to translate that ASP.net stuff. Moreover, where is `document.getElementById('rowtxtConsidAmt')`?

Comment: ASP.net stuff has a nasty tendency to translate to different HTML depending on the browser's user-agent header too. (So compare the output in IE and 'mozilla')

Answer (score 1):

According to the [IE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `getElementById` is case-insensitive for versions less than 8. According to the [Firefox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) `getElementById` is case-sensitive. So you need to verify that your casing is the same between the HTML and what you pass to `getElementById`.